# ssh connection refused; netstat LISTEN; nmap closed

Tags: server, 18.04, ssh, nmap, netstat

**My Setup**

- `Ubuntu server 18.04` on local hardware
- A laptop from which I want to `ssh` into the server over local network

**My Problem**

Every once in a while right after boot, I can `ssh` into the machine for a few minutes. But most of the time I simply get: `connect to host 192.168.0.101 port 22: Connection refused`.

**On the server**

- I disabled the firewall: `sudo ufw disable`, but didn't help.
- Then I checked  `netstat -nlpt` and it told me that `sshd` is listening on port 22.

**On my laptop**

- But then I tried `nmap -v -p 22 192.168.0.101` and it told me  that port 22 was closed.

I am very confused why `netstat` and `nmap` tell me different things. Could it be that my wifi-router is blocking ssh somehow?

Edit\Update:

All other devices on the network were assigned to addresses in the low 100 range (102,104...) (non-static ip). After changing the static address of my server to 192.168.0.2XX it works.

Comment: You say it works for couple of minutes and then it stops. I would focus on that part in troubleshooting. What happens before it stops working? Try to run both those commands when things work after a reboot and then again after it stops working.
Also, any chance there is duplicate IP on your network? Unless you configure something specifucally, home routers have no reason to block traffic inside LAN. And again, you say it works for some time and then it stops...

Comment: Also check cron jobs on the server

Comment: @marosg thanks. You might be right about the duplicate IP. I changed the ip address to 2XX and suddenly it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, you just need to run:

```
service sshd start
service ssh restart
```